# How to take a value from if statements to directly get information from an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a simple array with the rows: a1, a 2 and a3 & columns: b1 and b2.
I am trying to write a simple program where a user can select one of these rows and one of these columns and then it will automatically give the user the value from the table. In the code below I have specified that I would like the value from row a1 and column b1 which should return 1. I have labelled the value for the rows as 'first_value' and the value for the columns as 'second_value'. Do you have any idea how I can modify the code below so that it will return the desired value automatically?

```
        string a = "a1";
        string b = "b1";
        int first_value;
        int second_value;

        if (a == "a1")
        {
            first_value = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(first_value);
        }

        else if (a == "a2")
        {
            first_value = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(first_value);
        }

        else if (a == "a3")
        {
            first_value = 2;
            Console.WriteLine(first_value);
        }

        if (b == "b1")
        {
            second_value = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(second_value);
        }

        else if (b == "b2")
        {
            second_value = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(second_value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(first_value);
        Console.WriteLine(second_value);

        int[,] array = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

        Console.WriteLine(array[first_value, second_value]);
```

Comment: Since the second character of each string is directly correlated to the index, why don't you parse the second character into an `int` and subtract `1` from it to get the actual index? You also should use better names. Maybe `firstIndex` and `secondIndex` instead of `value`

Comment: @Everyone: It's not impossible that "a1" is an example value here; not a literal one.

Comment: @Flater if `a1` can be `whatever1` and `b1` can be `something1` then a dictionary is recommended. However, if that's the case, then he probably have to ask another question, lol.

Comment: @Everyone: I see no reason to ask a different question. The whole point of algorithms is that they work independent of the exact value of a const (or, in this case, literal string). Should OP have specified that the numbers may not always be present in the strings, if that is indeed the case? Sure. But that's a footnote; not a reason to invalidate the question and have OP repost the exact same question again.

Comment: @Flater That's not what I meant. I meant if the values can be arbitrary then it's likely not a good design. In such case, the question should be about improving the design to make it follow some reasonable standard.

Comment: @Everyone: There is not enough information in the question for your conclusion. Header/Row names might be parametrized for different files. Or OP may simple be using literal strings values _other than_ "a1", or he might actually be using the literal string value "a1". The answer to this question is independent of how the header/row names are defined, as long as they are used consistently within scope of a single execution.

Comment: Dear all, "a1" and "b1" are indeed example values here. I probably should have chosen different ones to make this a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary:

```
var valueDict = new Dictionary<string, int> {{"a1",0},{"a2",1},{"a3",2},{"b1",0},{"b2",1}};

if (valueDict.ContainsKey(a))
{
    first_value = valueDict[a];
    Console.WriteLine(first_value);
}

if (valueDict.ContainsKey(b))
{
    second_value = valueDict[b];
    Console.WriteLine(second_value);
}
```

A generic dictionary in a sequence of key-value pairs, where you can lookup by the key. It's in System.Collections.Generic.
Please not that this solution allows you to enter "a1" for b, and vice versa. To circumvent that you could use two separate dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function like this:

```
int getIndex(string str){
    if(str.Length < 2) return -1;
    string numStr = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 1);

    int ret;
    try{
        ret Int.Parse(numStr);
    } catch {
        ret = -1;
    }
    if(ret == -1) return ret;
    return ret - 1;
}
```

This way you can pass the string, it will parse all the characters after the first one, and return the index which you can directly use.

Example:

```
string indexStr1 = Console.ReadLine();
string indexStr2 = Console.ReadLine();
int index1 = getIndex(indexStr1);
int index2 = getIndex(indexStr2);
if(index1 == -1 || index2 == -1) {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid index provided");
    return;
}

int[,] array = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

Console.WriteLine(array[index1, index2]);
```